# Link to another page with anchor to id

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I've seen similar questions here, but none of them seemed to have a working solution.

I'm on Wordpress, BeTheme. I have a long page of services, where I use anchor links leadings to elements that are lower on the same page, and they work as expected. ex.

```
<a href="#id-name">text</a>
```

I need to add links that can land from any other page to the same elements, lower on the target page.

```
<a href="https://www.url.com/en/#id_name>text</a>
```

And what happens is, sometimes it seems to land on the id indicated by the anchor, and then immediately jump back to top, and others it seemingly just lands directly at the top of the page as if the anchor id wasn't there at all in the link.

Could it be that clicking on the link lands you at the correct element, but before the page has fully loaded, and when it loads it jumps you back up to the top?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There is not problem with what you described. It has to be a new action for the permalink to work. If you're just refreshing the session/page with an anchor attach to the url, the previous session state (page scroll location) will get returned instead of the anchor state. It's  an intended behaviour.

Comment: I'm not just refreshing the page. If <a href="https://www.url.com/en/#id_name>text</a> is clicked from any other page it will land on the element with id = id_name and immediately jump up to the top of the page.

Comment: Default behaviour isn't to jump back to the top of the page. Are you sure no javascript (eg: scrolling script / scroll smoothing ... ) not plugins is creating trouble shooting?